# Express Serving Static Files

Tags: node.js, express

I'm just learning how to use Express, and am trying to serve the static files, like the bootstrap.min.css file.

Here's my folder structure:

```
server.js
/server
    /includes
        layout.jade
    /public
        /css
        /vendor
            /bootstrap
                /dist
                    /css
                        bootstrap.min.css
    /views
        index.jade
```

I'm using `wiredep` in my Gulpfile.js, and have tried several different variations of the configuration, and haven't gotten anything. Here's my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use('/server', express.static('public'));
app.set('views', './server/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

require('./server/routes/routes')(app);

app.listen(port, function(err) {
    console.log('running server on port: ' + port);
});
```

I've tried a couple different ways setting the `express.static` part, but again, it isn't serving the static files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to add that `wiredep` is adding this as the path: `href='../public/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'`. I've tried using the ignorePath option for `wiredep` too, but it hasn't helped much.

Comment: check below link http://only4ututorials.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-serve-static-file-in-express-js.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/server/public'));
```

on link tag

```
href = "vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.